# Plot voiced data over original data from sound file in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, plot

Our pogram takes sound file, divides it into frames and finds voiced unvoiced frames using Zero Cross Rate and Short term energy. At some point algorithm finds all ids of voiced frames. We want to create good graphic representation for voiced frames but we don't succeed to mark voiced frames over original data using plot.
Now we only succeed to show voiced frames without unvoiced (at the beginning of the graph):

[Now it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLJXw.png)

But we want to do something like this (made with graphic editor) so you will be able to see voiced frames on original data plot):

[We want image to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23tRZ.png)

Code:

```html
close all; clear all;

% read sound 
[data, fs] = audioread('shee_mono.wav');
% normalize data
data = data / abs(max(data));

f_d = 0.025

%[frames, ~] = vec2frames( data, Nw, Ns, 'rows', @hamming, false); 
frames = framing(data, fs, f_d);
ZCR_values_per_frame = ZCR(frames, f_d, fs, data);
f_energy_vector =  STECalc(frames);

ste_threshold = 0.01;
  
zcr_threshold = mean(ZCR_values_per_frame); %take average ZCR as threshold

voiced_id = find_voiced_id(ZCR_values_per_frame, f_energy_vector, zcr_threshold, ste_threshold);

unvoiced_id = reshape(1:size(frames), 1, []); %create vector filled with numbers 1...96 in order
unvoiced_id = setdiff(unvoiced_id, voiced_id); %change vector to be every frame that is unvoiced

fr_unvoiced = frames(unvoiced_id,:); 
data_unvoiced = reshape(fr_unvoiced',1,[]);

fr_voiced = frames(voiced_id,:); 
data_voiced = reshape(fr_voiced',1,[]);

figure
plot(data); hold on;
%plot(data_unvoiced, 'b'); 
%plot(data_voiced, 'g');
sound(data_voiced, fs);
title ("Blue - original data, green - voiced areas after unvoiced deleted");
[ voiced_timing, unvoiced_timing ] = return_voiced_unvoiced_timings(voiced_id, unvoiced_id, f_d, frames);
```

P.S. Sorry if there are some mistakes. English is not my native language

[Code in Github repo](https://github.com/danrol/SpeechRecognitionFinalProject)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is make a time vector, `tv`, based on the sample frequency and number of samples:

```
tv = (0:numel(data)-1)/fs;
```

Then, you could use `voiced_id` (this contains the indices of the sound segments you want to obtain, looking at your Github repo) to obtain the time vector that corresponds to the time stamps of the data you want:

```
tv_voice = tv(voiced_id);
```

Then plot, using the time vector as x values:

```
plot(tv,data, 'b');
plot(tv_voice, data_voiced, 'g');
```

Comment: Matlab throws me error that says: "Error using plot
Vectors must be the same length."
"Error in main (line 46)
plot(tv_voice, data_voiced, 'g');" like this: [link] (https://imgur.com/a/im8w2ZG). From what I understand it's because of different dimensions of "tv_voiced" and "data_voiced". Added your solution to Github repo. Maybe you know how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.